# apache modsecurity SecRule ipmatch errors

Tags: linux, apache, mod-security

I am using:
apache2-2.4.25-5.1.x86_64
apache2-mod_security2-2.9.0-6.1.x86_64

> Apr 13 18:59:36 mail start_apache2[16810]: AH00526: Syntax error on
>   line 1 of /etc/apache2/mod_security2.d/crs_whitelist.conf:
>
> Apr 13 18:59:36 mail start_apache2[16810]: ModSecurity: Execution phases
>   can only be specified by chain starter rules.

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipmatch 192.168.3.0/24"   "phase:1,t:none,nolog,noauditlog,ctl:ruleRemovebyID=920350,id:999001"
```

I am trying to prevent logging of certain rules when accessing my web server locally.

Modsecurity cause apache not to start because of above error.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any more rules? Is line 1 of /etc/apache2/mod_security2.d/crs_whitelist.conf the one above?

The second error refers to a chained rule, that is, 2 rules in a single one that generate a logical condition = AND, both rules must be true to be applied any action.